# How to search for a specific field using getCriteria()?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

I'm looking at making a plugin and need to search news entries.
I can use:

```php
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'news';
$find = $criteria->find();
```

However, I want to add a criteria where I search a specific field, for example: `fieldabc = 'zyx'`

What is the correct syntax for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I see I can use: $criteria->search = 'zyx'; which would suffice, but is there a way to target it to a field ?

Comment: Hey Anthony, great question! Can you update the title to something a little more descriptive like "How to search for a specific field using getCriteria"? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

As per the (new) ["Working with Elements"](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) guide from the docs, it works the same as from your templates.

> The actual list of available parameters depends on the element type. They are identical to the parameters available to your templates.

So this template example:

```
{% craft.entries.section('news').myPlaintextField('xyz').myLightswitchField(1) %}
```

Works from your plugin like so:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section            = 'news';
$criteria->myPlaintextField   = 'xyz';
$criteria->myLightswitchField = 1;
```

Using custom field parameters is a fast and reliable solution if you are looking for EXACT matches. I would only use the `search` parameter if there's no other solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the a special search format.

```php
$criteria-> search = 'fieldHandle:searchstring';
```

Learn more about [searching](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Remember to check the status.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->slug = $slug;
$criteria->status = NULL;
```